# Unable to add collumn in mongo

Tags: mongodb

Something strange in this neighbourhood. Calling DBA's and ! GB

```
db.getCollection('contacts').update({}, {$set: {"source": "domain.txt"}},false,true);
```

It failed with:

```
admin> db.getCollection('contacts').update({}, {$set: {"source": "domain.txt"}},false,true);
[2020-09-29 23:24:32] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: options should be an object: false
[2020-09-29 23:24:32] options should be an object: false
```

Also, table feels a little corrupted. No longer displays the amount of records.

Based on answers from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7714216/add-new-field-to-every-document-in-a-mongodb-collection

Answer (score 1):

Turns out mongo cli client needs to be on version 4.4
I had version 3